# MSI Package with JAVA application

Tags: java, c++, windows-installer

I want to create an MSI package which should have C++  code along with Tomcat and few other java applications ? Can you please suggest way to solve this ?

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for Docker which can package the whole lot in a running form.